# Android make JSoup element's text bold

Tags: android, html, jsoup

I am parsing an element in android using [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/%22JSoup%22-).

What I would like to do is **take the element that I receive and make it bold**.

Is there something I can do to the element using JSoup to make it bold or is there another library I could use to achieve this?

Comment: Do you wish to display it in bold (e.g. in a TextView) or edit the HTML of the element to make it bold?

Comment: @ashatte I would like to edit the html to bold it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method `Element.Wrap(String html);` to achieve this.

Suppose you have the following HTML:

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body> 
  <p>Make me bold!</p> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Element p = doc.select("p:eq(0)").first();
        p.wrap("");

Using the suggested method above

```
Element p = doc.select("p").first();
p.wrap("<b>");
System.out.println(doc);
```

will print out

```
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body> 
  <b><p>Make me bold!</p></b> 
 </body>
</html>
```

---

Consider looking through the documentation, particularly the `Element` class, since that is the one that you wish to modify. Getting familiar with the different methods is a good way to easily find intuitive answers to your questions. Also, try experimenting with the code.

[class Element - jsoup 1.7.3](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#wrap%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: how would I make this bold:

Comment: <body> 
                 Make me bold!
             </body>

Comment: could you see my other answer I just posted? thanks.